# When to use @extend and @mixin in Sass

Tags: css, sass

I am learning Sass in its [official tutorial](http://sass-lang.com/guide).

When I learned `@mixin` and `@extend`, I know both of them is for CSS code reuse, but I just cannot figure out when to use which one. There are two differences for me.

1. `@mixin` can take the arguments(but `@extend` cannot?), which is good, it works like a function.
2. `@extend` can make your output CSS contains less code, like this output CSS `(.message, .success, .error, .warning { })` in its official tutorial.

Currently, I only know that, if I want to take extra arguments, I will use `@mixin`. If I want to have less output CSS code, I will use `@extend`. Except those two, I can pick either one to use. Am I correct?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are on the right way.

You should use a mixin when you want the output to change depending on how you call it.

So, in some cases using a `%placeholder` and `@extend` would have produced less CSS.
It is important to realise that @extend creates relationships. Whenever you use `@extend`, you are transplanting a selector elsewhere in your stylesheet in order for it to share traits with other selectors that are also being transplanted.

**EXTEND**

e.g.

```
.awesome {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    @extend .awesome;
}
p {
    @extend .awesome;
}
```

Which returns:

```
.awesome, body, p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

**MIXIN**

```
@mixin awesome {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    @include awesome;
}
p {
    @include awesome;
}
```

Will return:

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

But with mixins you can have parameters like:

```
@mixin awesome($w: 100%, $h: 100%) {
    width: $w;
    height: $h;
}

body {
    @include awesome(960px);
}
p {
    @include awesome;
}
```

Which returns:

```
body {
    width: 960px;
    height: 100%;
}
p {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Hope this was helpful!

Additional:

The `@extend` directive isn’t flexible. You can’t pass arguments to it so what’s there is there. There are also limitations on using `@extend` inside `@media` directives and you can’t extend a selector across different media directives using `@extend`.

The main advantage to using mixins is the power and flexibility they have because they can accept arguments. Naturally, if you want to pass arguments, you’ll have to choose `@mixin` over `@extend`.

They are kind of interchangeable, it depends also if you want/have to stick to DRY CSS or not.

**EXTEND**

```
%hide-text {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.foo {
  @extend %hide-text;
}

.bar {
  @extend %hide-text;
}

.baz {
  @extend %hide-text;
}
```

Nice and clean result:

```
.foo, .bar, .baz {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

**MIXIN**

```
@mixin hide-text {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.foo {
  @include hide-text;
}

.bar {
  @include hide-text;
}

.baz {
  @include hide-text;
}
```

Result:

```
.foo {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bar {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.baz {
  text-indent: -9999px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

You can see there's no relation between the CSS selectors.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But actually, I thought your answer is the same when I learn '@mixin' and '@extend' in its tutorial (http://sass-lang.com/guide). I am more concerned with when to use which one except for the two cases I mentioned in my post.

Comment: Uhm..I've added some more info, let me know if you need a deeper explanation

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you please provide the reference document for your added info? Your added info looks like is an explanation for my two cases in my post? Do you have more info besides my two cases?

Comment: I guess that's all. Do you want some other code examples?

Comment: Yes, please. It would be helpful.

Comment: @Alessio, Creating relationships in rulesets, is it matters in compiled CSS? How could this effect? Can you please give more explanation?

Comment: @SunilGarg yes, of course it matters in compiled CSS. You have to use it  carefully in order not to create relationship you don't want. It's better use extends only to share rules among similar elements. It's quite long to explain here, but I can share some useful resources.

https://csswizardry.com/2014/11/when-to-use-extend-when-to-use-a-mixin/ 

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/05/extending-in-sass-without-mess/

Hope it will help you

Answer (score 4):

`@extend` extends rules inside of rules in essence creating inheritance.

```
.button {
  color: black;
}
.submit-button {
  @extend .button;
  border 1px black solid;
}
```

Results in:

```
.submit-button {
  border: 1px black solid;
}
.button, .submit-button {
  color: black;
}
```

Use `@extend` when you want to inherit a rule

`@mixin` creates repeatable sections of code, more like functions

```
@mixin large-font {
  font: {
    size: 14px;
    family: san-serif;
    weight: bold;
  }
}

#form {
  @include large-font;
}
```

Use `@mixin` when you know you'll be repeating yourself a lot. Creating `@mixin` helps you avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a scenario using both, taking advantage of both.

Define an `icon` `@mixin` so that we can change the size of the icon by passing the parameters `width` and `height`. And, we use `@extend` to inherit the `.icon` class, generating less CSS code.

```
@import './mixins.scss';

@mixin icon($width: 18px, $height: 18px) {
  display: inline-block;
  width: $width;
  height: $height;
  @include cover-background;
}

.icon {
  @include icon();

  &-edit {
    @extend .icon;
    background-image: url('https://cdn-health.zhongan.com/hic-test/model/endorsement_back_insurance_retention/du/Md8C__csgu.png');
  }
  &-notice {
    @extend .icon;
    background-image: url('https://cdn-health.zhongan.com/hic-test/model/endorsement_back_insurance_retention/du/Sgnm1KiefR.png');
  }
}
```

We use the `.icon-edit` class in HTML element:

```
<i class='icon-edit'></i>
```

The generated CSS:

```css
.icon-edit {
   background-image: url('https://cdn-health.zhongan.com/hic-test/model/endorsement_back_insurance_retention/du/Md8C__csgu.png');
}

.icon, .icon-notice, .icon-edit {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```